# JIT debugging not showing for WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, debugging, jit

I'm running an WPF application on a different computer than I am developing it on. Currently I am only using the files from Debug instead of Release. I notice that when I run an application made in Windows Forms, a JIT debugging window shows up when an unhandled exception occurs. This is not the case for my WPF application though. I've check my visual studio settings and I have JIT enabled. Installing visual studio on the computer where the application needs to run is not really possible. Is there a way I can get the JIT debugging window to show up? I am having a real pain in trying to figure out what is going on when the application crashes and doesn't give me any information about it.

Comment: When a .Net app crashes, you should have a related entry with the stack in the Windows event viewer (Application log). It will contain the same stack trace as the popup. So it should be enough to let you analyze the issue

Comment: Hi @OlivierDepriester the application just crashes without any pop up window with details of the crash

Comment: I know, just look the event viewer > Application log > Entries with ".NET Runtime" source

Comment: @OlivierDepriester Sorry budd you're talking to a rookie here. Where is event viewer?

Comment: Type ```eventvwr``` in a cmd

Comment: @OlivierDepriester Okay I'll check that. So is there not a way to get the dialog window pop up with an unhandled exception as you get with a Windows Forms app?

Comment: Actually I don't know as it is not a kind of feature that developers usually look for. Letting the stack trace be displayed to the end-user is not really a best practice.

Comment: @OlivierDepriester I have found an answer on the following link. https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/wpf-application/handling-exceptions/ I've made it an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've not been able to replicate the windows form unhandled exception window but I've got the next best thing using this article:

https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/wpf-application/handling-exceptions/

Adding the following code into app.xaml

```
DispatcherUnhandledException="Application_DispatcherUnhandledException"
```

And the following code into app.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void Application_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An unhandled exception just occurred: " + e.Exception.Message, "Exception Sample", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

I get a MessageBox telling me what the error is. It also handles the exception and allows the application to continue running.